# Magento 2 : Override block file Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php

Tags: magento2, overrides

How to override `function getAllowProducts()` from `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php` in magento 2.

I want to override above function but not getting changes of function and nothing display any issue.
There are no any error display inside log file.

i will share my code here,

`registration.php` file,

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Configuration',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc folder,

```
module.xml
```

code is,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Test_Configuration" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

i have override block inside
    `di.xml` code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Test\Configuration\Block\Outstock" />
</config>
```

Block folder,
`Outstock.php` file,

```
<?php
namespace Test\Configuration\Block;

class Outstock extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable
{
    public function getAllowProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
            $products = [];
            $skipSaleableCheck = $this->catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck();
            $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($this->getProduct(), null);
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                    $products[] = $product;
            }
            $this->setAllowProducts($products);
        }
        return $this->getData('allow_products');
    }   

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable'));
        return parent::_toHtml();
    } 
}
```

i havent any error display not any log generate for this file and module is activated. inside `setup_module` entry are generated.

Any suggestion for override function of `configurable.php` file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't have to override the preference and you should not.

You can easily use a Plugin to set the allow_products data before the method is called. You find a nice tutorial about plugins here:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system

To create your Plugin, you first need to add a type to your etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
    <plugin name="changeAllowProductsBehaviour" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable\Plugin" sortOrder="10" />
</type>
```

Then Your Plugin Class should look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable;

class Plugin
{
    /**
     * getAllowProducts
     *
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeGetAllowProducts($subject)
    {
        if (!$subject->hasData('allow_products')) {
            $products = [];
            $allProducts = $subject->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($subject->getProduct(), null);
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                    $products[] = $product;
            }
            $subject->setData('allow_products', $products);
        }

        return [];
    }

}
```

Be sure to clear cache and also your var/generation dir to have this changes applied

Comment: its not working for me using plugin method. page disappear and only select box display with null value in whole page.

Comment: then there is most likely still an error somewhere. Check you error logs in magento and also your webserver error log. Do you have developer mode enabled in .htaccess file? Also I was not sure if you have to return an empty array or rather nothing when the orgininal method has no arguments (should not make a difference but could)

Comment: i have to display out of stock products option in dropdown so i have to remove if condition from above function but using plugin its not working also not display any error log.any suggestion.

Comment: Now that your'e asking this way, it may be sufficient if you just change the configuration to show out of stock products in frontend. In your backend go to Stores -> Configuration. Then Choose Catalog->Inventory Tab and change display out of stock products to yes

Comment: those settings i have did, i want to display out of stock product options inside config product. by default out of stock products config options not display inside dropdown of config product detail page. so i have to display those options in dropdown.

Comment: ok, just testet both. The setting does not really apply here. The Plugin does work, there was a simple mistake. There still is a call to $this->getProduct() which has to be changed to $subject->getProduct(). I'll Update the answer

Comment: error like, Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given in /var/www/html/buytea/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 144

Comment: I just tested the code. Did you clear your cache and var/generation folder? Did you maybe forget the return [] at the end. This error message might be coming from that

Comment: that's weird. You're using the 2.0.2 stalbe version? Any other Modules that could disturb? Still no errors? Only a white page. Can't explain it, its working perfectly here

Answer (score 13):

For Magento2.1 version  you need to override `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable`

1) Create `di.xml`  file in Folder `Namespace\Module\etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" type="Namespace\Module\Block\Outstock" />
</config>
```

2) Create `Outstock.php` Block file in Folder `Namespace\Module\Block`

```
<?php 

namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

class Outstock extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
{

    public function getAllowProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
            $products = [];
            $skipSaleableCheck = $this->catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck();
            $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($this->getProduct(), null);
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {
                    $products[] = $product;
                }
            }
            $this->setAllowProducts($products);
        }
        return $this->getData('allow_products');
    }


}
```

Comment: Should be type="Namespace\Module\Block\ Outstock"

Comment: but it doesn't work for list page, Why ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to override

```
Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
```

instead of overriding

```
Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable
```

file.

Comment: but it doesn't work for list page, Why ?

Answer (score 1):

## To override function of configurable.php file.

1) First create di.xml file in Folder Test/Configuration/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Test\Configuration\Block\Outstock" />
</config>
```

2) Now create Outstock.php Block file in Folder Test\Configuration\Block

```
<?php 

namespace Test\Configuration\Block;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable;

class Outstock extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable
{

    public function getAllowProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
            $products = [];
            $skipSaleableCheck = $this->catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck();
            $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($this->getProduct(), null);
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {
                    $products[] = $product;
                }
            }
            $this->setAllowProducts($products);
        }
        return $this->getData('allow_products');
    }


}
```

Comment: but it doesn't work for list page, Why ?

Comment: How to override  \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable i am trying but not working above code

Comment: In my requirement  configurable product  option drop down remove "Custom option" label