# how can i add a function in magento2 success page?

Tags: magento2, php-7

this is my block/success page. and can you please help me to add a function in this page ?

```
namespace Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

/**
 * One page checkout success page
 */
class Success extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config
     */
    protected $_orderConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    /**
     * Render additional order information lines and return result html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdditionalInfoHtml()
    {

        return $this->_layout->renderElement('order.success.additional.info');
    }


    /**
     * Initialize data and prepare it for output
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->prepareBlockData();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Prepares block data
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareBlockData()
    {
        $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();

        $this->addData(
            [
                'is_order_visible' => $this->isVisible($order),
                'view_order_url' => $this->getUrl(
                    'sales/order/view/',
                    ['order_id' => $order->getEntityId()]
                ),
                'print_url' => $this->getUrl(
                    'sales/order/print',
                    ['order_id' => $order->getEntityId()]
                ),
                'can_print_order' => $this->isVisible($order),
                'can_view_order'  => $this->canViewOrder($order),
                'order_id'  => $order->getIncrementId()
            ]
        );


    }



    /**
     * Is order visible
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isVisible(Order $order)
    {
        return !in_array(
            $order->getStatus(),
            $this->_orderConfig->getInvisibleOnFrontStatuses()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Can view order
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function canViewOrder(Order $order)
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)
            && $this->isVisible($order);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the block class to add a function. Check here how you can do that
[Magento 2 : Override block file Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101631/magento-2-override-block-file-magento-configurableproduct-block-product-view-t)

then you have to override the `success.phtml` template by copying it under you theme like

from

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\success.phtml
```

to

```
app\design\frontend\<VENDOR_NAME>\<THEME_NAME>\Magento_Checkout\templates\success.phtml
```

Comment: thanks, by using this i can create a module with a function, then how can i call that function at success page

Comment: Answer updated!

Answer (score 0):

You Will need to create a module to achieve this and override block class
same as above.In your module in view folder add referenceContainer name "order.success.additional.info". From this block call your phtml file.

follow module that is used for same purpose

https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-sample-cronjob/tree/master/PHPCuong/SampleConversionTracking

Hope this will help you.